# Проверить активность соединения

Tags: php, apache2

Есть два Инет-провайдера. которые "отваливаются" с непредсказуемой периодичностью. Соответственно, у сервера есть два IP (от двух инет провайдеров), между которыми приходится переключаться для поддержания сайта (с сервера идет подгрузка данных).

Задача - проверить, какое соединение активно. Желательно побыстрее...
Что пробовал: создал файл на сервере и проверяю по какому запросу (через какой IP) он доступен. Но...

`is_readable, file_exists` - ложь при активном соединении

`fopen, file_get_contents` - соответствуют ситуации, но "крутятся" довольно долго

`get_headers` - иногда не срабатывает (не дает заголовки, хотя файл открывается или отдается)

Вопросы: Как лучше всего проверить активность соединения? Логичный ли путь я избрал? Может, идея читать файл не лучшая, а стоит попробовать коннектиться к БД?

Answer (score 1):

> "fopen, file_get_contents" - соответствуют ситуации, но "крутятся"
>   довольно долго.

И, тем не менее, самый надёжный способ проверить, доступен ли сервер по определённому IP-адресу - это попробовать соединиться. Сетевое соединение это долго в любом случае (если только не с гарантированно работающим сервером в одном дата-центре), поэтому имеет смысл эту проверку делать как-то асинхронно и регулярно. Например по крону запускать скрипт, который будет проверять соединение и записывать IP-адрес в простой файл. Так что когда появляется необходимость воспользоваться соединением, уже известно по какому адресу нужно обращаться - считать его из файла.

Вообще, похоже вам нужно посмотреть в сторону какого-то load-balancer'а (LB). Например HAProxy. Принцип такой, что этот LB слушает локальный порт, который и будет использовать ваш сайт. А LB уже автоматически направляет запрос на нужный внешний ресурс, автоматически мониторя, какой из них доступен.

Вот пара описаний настройки HAProxy для такой конфигурации (на английском; если в английском не сильны, можно поискать аналогичное по-русски):
https://www.haproxy.com/blog/failover-and-worst-case-management-with-haproxy/
https://serverfault.com/questions/473445/haproxy-switch-only-in-case-of-server-down

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Сайт на хостинге, сервер отдельно. Установить прокси или слушателя у хостера довольно непросто. Поэкспериментирую еще с попытками подключиться к БД. Может, получится быстрее